# How to get ALL NFTs form a 'collectionId' on Shimmer L1

Tags: iota-network, shimmer

Going of Anotnio's answer here, we are able to dial into the NFTs.

[How to keep track of an NFT or a collection of NFTs on L1?](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/2915/how-to-keep-track-of-an-nft-or-a-collection-of-nfts-on-l1)

This get's me to the immutable data we are looking for, including the collectionID, which we can use in the Shimmer Explorer to check and see all of the NFT's that are part of that collection via the Associated Outputs.

https://explorer.shimmer.network/shimmer/addr/smr1zqzpuas8xqn2l2c4mwhgdm4jclwksakyv09rnlsr7ch7euwhk6exstatc2m?tab=AssocOutputs

The roadblock I am now having is using python to get that information based on the collectionID, or even using the indexer to do so. I'm sure I am missing something on my end but what I can not tell.

Any ideas on how to go about listing all the associated outputs / nfts based on a collectionID?

Answer (score 0):

The indexer has an issuer filter, so you can get other NFTs from https://api.shimmer.network/api/indexer/v1/outputs/nft?issuer=smr1zqzpuas8xqn2l2c4mwhgdm4jclwksakyv09rnlsr7ch7euwhk6exstatc2m

Answer (score 0):

There is a [bug](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota-sdk/pull/666) in the current iota.rs lib.
But it should be fixed in the first release of the new IOTA SDK.

Than you will be able to do something like this:

```
from iota_sdk import Client, NodeIndexerAPI

# Create a Client instance
client = Client(nodes=['https://api.shimmer.network'])

query_parameters = NodeIndexerAPI.QueryParameters(
    issuer='smr1zqzpuas8xqn2l2c4mwhgdm4jclwksakyv09rnlsr7ch7euwhk6exstatc2m',
)

# Get output ids of nft output with 
output_ids_response = client.nft_output_ids(query_parameters)
print(len(output_ids_response.items))

# Get the outputs by their id
outputs = client.get_outputs(output_ids_response.items)
print(f'{outputs}')
```